# Select all from A and join all non-repeating combinations from B so that : ab, ac, ad, abc, abd... in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, combinations

I have a table **A** with food products.

I have a table **B** with food addons.

Table **B** has the fields:

- price
- added_calories
- name
- products

I want to make such query that will get the top 10 (or more) combinations of product and addons that will result the best **calories** / **price** ratio . I need to keep the names of the **addons** and **product** to display to the user.

I should be able to have several addons on 1 product so that I should try and run through all combinations.

If we have addons **a**, **b**, **c**, **d** then I have to try the combinations:

- Product + a
- Product + b
- Product + ab
- Product + ac
- Product + ad
- Product + bc
- Product + bd
- ...

Not every addon can be selected for each product. There's an additional 'connector' table which indicates supported addons for a product.

Comment: Can every addon go to any/every product?

Comment: No, I'll add this to the description. Thank you.

Comment: Some sample data with expected results might be helpful.  Also, can you post the table schemas of all your tables involved?  Something like this? http://sqlize.com/obl05G5h10

Comment: I would think this is something that will be an overkill to have MySQL do, and would be better off processed by the client code. But will be interested to see if there is any good way to have MySQL do it.

Comment: Besides the difficulty, the problem is somewhat ill-defined. **Lowest price** or **highest calories**? Or **highest ratio of calories/price**? Which of the above is to be optimized?

Comment: I didn't know about sqlize.com! Thank you. I will use it in the future. @ypercube, yes I need the calories/price ratio. I'll fix the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to maximize calories / price, I think this *is* doable.  The trick is that, given a specific product, you'll maximize calories / price by piling on add-ons, in descending order by calories / price ratio, until the total ratio starts to decrease.

The following query is probably ridiculously inefficient and in need of serious optimization, but at least it shows that a solution exists:

```
SELECT
  p.name AS product,
  GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) AS additives,
  p.price + COALESCE(SUM(a.price), 0) AS price,
  p.calories + COALESCE(SUM(a.added_calories), 0) AS calories,
  (p.calories + COALESCE(SUM(a.added_calories), 0)) /
    (p.price + COALESCE(SUM(a.price), 0)) AS calories_per_price
FROM
  products AS p
  LEFT JOIN connector AS c ON c.product = p.id
  LEFT JOIN additives AS a
    ON a.id = c.additive
    AND (a.added_calories / a.price) > (
      (p.calories + COALESCE((
        SELECT SUM(b.added_calories) FROM connector AS d, additives AS b
        WHERE d.product = p.id AND b.id = d.additive
          AND (b.added_calories / b.price) > (a.added_calories / a.price)
      ), 0)) /
      (p.price + COALESCE((
        SELECT SUM(b.price) FROM connector AS d, additives AS b
        WHERE d.product = p.id AND b.id = d.additive
          AND (b.added_calories / b.price) > (a.added_calories / a.price)
      ), 0))
    )
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY calories_per_price DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**Edit:** OK, I debugged it, now it actually works(!).  Here's some test data:

```
INSERT INTO products (id, name, calories, price) VALUES
  (1, 'Cardboard', 0, 1),
  (2, 'Lard', 1000, 100),
  (3, 'Spaghetti', 10, 50);
INSERT INTO additives (id, name, added_calories, price) VALUES
  (1, 'Salt', 0, 2),
  (2, 'Butter', 500, 100),
  (3, 'Cheese', 300, 70),
  (4, 'Pepper', 0, 3),
  (5, 'Ketchup', 50, 10),
  (6, 'Milk', 20, 10);
INSERT INTO connector (product, additive) VALUES
  (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6),
  (2,1), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5),
  (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4), (3,5);
```

And results:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+-------+----------+--------------------+
| product   | additives             | price | calories | calories_per_price |
+-----------+-----------------------+-------+----------+--------------------+
| Lard      | NULL                  |   100 |     1000 |                 10 | 
| Cardboard | Butter,Ketchup        |   111 |      550 |   4.95495495495495 | 
| Spaghetti | Butter,Cheese,Ketchup |   230 |      860 |   3.73913043478261 | 
+-----------+-----------------------+-------+----------+--------------------+
```

**Edit 2:** Oops, I had it maximizing price per calories instead of calories per price. Fixed.

**Edit 3:** The subqueries were ignoring the connector table.  I've (hopefully) fixed that bug, but I haven't been able to test it yet.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. I'd never seen GROUP_CONCAT before.

Comment: To be honest, neither had I, but I sort of figured that MySQL ought to have something like it, and found it in [this list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: Thank you! I still can't completely understand the logic but if it works I'll investigate further - a description would be appreciated. Anyone knows how to optimize this or should I create a new question?